# How to fetch stock price dynamically from Yahoo Finance using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to fetch the real-time Last-traded stock price from yahoo finance without using yahoo api. I'm using python for this project. So far I was able to fetch statics contents from yahoo finance using beautiful soup. But when it comes to dynamic content, i become clueless as HTML requests does not copy the dynamic content.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"data from pandas_datareader" is perfect for this.  In your code, simply import "data" from "pandas_datareader" and read up on the documentation for DataReader

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

start= datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)  # The start of the year for example
end= datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 13)
ticker= "APPL"  # Apple stock for example
df= data.DataReader(name= ticker, data_source= "yahoo", start= start, end= end)
```

You can use this for other finincial websites too.

Hope this helps.